# Two UARTs on MCU: FreeRTOS required (or wise)?

Tags: stm32, uart, modbus, freertos

I want to use a small stm32G0 with two UARTs:

- one RX receiving ~300 bytes from RFID reader, around once per second, 115kbaud. I parse the message to simple Modbus data every time I receive it (CRC check involved)
- one with RX receiving a 8 byte request (Modbus) every second and a TX calculating a CRC and sending out a 40 bytes response after 30-200ms (Modbus). 9600baud.

Furthermore there are no tasks.

I understand this can be done using FreeRTOS, but I am new to that, will figure it out though, but I wonder whether it could ever be as stable as  when keeping it simple. But I have to admit, I have not figured out how I could keep this simple:

- receive a 300 byte message around every second (not fixed), check CRC16, parsing out about 10 floating point values (in ascii), convert those to IEEE754 floating points, ready to be requested (some of them, or all of them)
- listen on the other RX for incoming Modbus request, retrieve the 1-10 floating point values, create a (=simple) message and calculate CRC16

Question I have is whether it can be even be done without freeRTOS. And if so, whether it is advisable.

Comment: RTOS makes it so much easier. It is wise, but not necessary. You do not even need to use C language - you can write it in assembler. Or if it hardcode version for a tough man - directly create the binary file without the assembler, compiler and linker

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need RTOS for this project.

There are 3 main parts:

1. Some logic to fill RFID RX buffer, using DMA and/or interrupts
2. Some logic to fill Modbus RX buffer, using DMA and/or interrupts
3. The main loop :

```
do forever {
    Process RFID RX buffer, parse text
    Possibly update Modbus registers using the parsed values
    Process Modbus RX buffer, arm USART TX DMA with the response
}
```

If this loop can execute before the Modbus master times out or before the RFID reader sends another package, you're done. If not, you can move your Modbus processing (which probably has tighter timing requirements than RFID) into an *ISR*. Normally, it's not a good idea to do time consuming work in *ISR*, but in your case I think it's okay considering that your uC doesn't have much to do.

Comment: Sounds good! Using two DMA buffers for receiving is more than I could think of. But it solves timing completely if you ask me. Not used DMA for RX before. Something to learn there. Sounds simply receiving to memory directly. 

I’m general, better than running RTOS overhead? You are right stating there are no other tasks. 

Would you say this is better than

Comment: @JeromeBu1982 , Although RTOS isn't needed in this project, using one may be a good learning practice. It may make programming easier by allowing to switch Modbus request processing while RFID parsing is in progress. Again, it's possible to achieve a similar effect using interrupts instead of RTOS, but it would be ugly. RTOS needs some memory overhead, but don't worry much about the execution time overhead.

Comment: Ok, great. So there are arguments for calling it ‘wise’ (or even ‘logical’). What about an freeRTOS application being stable? Will it run for years as own code with good memory management would? I have 32kB flash and 8kb RAM

Comment: FreeRTOS takes about ~8kB flash, depending on your configuration. I don't know about the RAM usage of the kernel itself. Stability isn't directly related to using an RTOS or not. But in general, avoid dynamic memory malloc() & free(), as they can cause memory fragmentation and harm the stability of the system. One time malloc() during initialization is probably fine, and this is what you generally do when using FreeRTOS.

Comment: I stay away from malloc… but does freeRTOS?

Comment: @JeromeBu1982 , It has its own dynamic allocation system, actually more than one to choose from. You can avoid them and use static allocation options it provides, but using static allocation needs some more coding. Take a look at the API reference.